# How to transform Json

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

If i have this object in node.js:

```
[ 
 { platform: 'iOS', quantity: 60 },
 { platform: 'Android', quantity: 28 },
 { platform: 'Windows Phone', quantity: 14 }
]
```

How can I transform it as follows?

```
[ 
 { 'iOS': 60 },
 { 'Android': 28 },
 { 'Windows Phone': 14 }
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

```
const xf = data => data.map(x => ({ [x.platform]: x.quantity }));
```

Comment: Answered from my phone, I hope there’re no typos.

Comment: thanks man. If i need get this:

{'iOS':60, 'Android':28, 'Windows Phone': 14}

output format json, not string.

Thanks again and best Rgs.